# "What doesn't kill you makes you stronger" or "what doesn't kill you make you stronger"

Tags: grammar, phrases

Of the two statements:

> - (1) What doesn't kill you makes you stronger.
> - (2) What doesn't kill you make you stronger.

Which one could be grammatically correct and why?

Comment: The correct question is: Which one is the idiom? It's the first. The second is not the truism in English.

Comment: ase include the example sentence in the body of the question, not just in the title. See [Asking Questions]("https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4785#4785") from the [*Contrinutors Guide*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners)

Answer (score 2):

Sentence (1) is grammatically correct. The form "*makes*" is the singular form of the verb, and is the proper form to use here. Sentence (2) is grammatically incorrect. The word "*make*" would be used if the subject were plural. For example:

> (2A) Those things that don't kill you make you stronger.

Sentence (1) is also a vary familiar and often quoted phrase, derived from the writing of the 19th century German philosopher Friedrich Nietzsche. The original German was:

> Aus der Kriegsschule des Lebens.—Was mich nicht umbringt, macht mich stärker,

and it appeared in *Twilight of the Idols* and was rested in modified form in Nietzsche's autobiography *Ecce Homo* It has been often quoted in English translation.

See ["What doesn’t kill you, makes you stronger"](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/what-doesnt-kill-you-makes-you-stronger/) from Dictionary.com's slang dictionary.

I would not call this an idiom. but it is certainly a much used fixed expression.